# what are the methods to reduce ticl4 to ticl3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I need the methods for reducing TiCl4 into TiCl3. I have searched for the methods ,but I couldn't find the answer. Please suggest me the methods

Comment: What have you searched for? Just saying "I have searched" isn't helpful at all.

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Various methods are described in detail in *Handbook of Preparative Inorganic Chemistry;* 2nd ed.; Brauer, G., Ed.; Academic Press: New York, NY, 1965; Volume 2, pp 1187–1192. (You may want to look up the details, such as the used equipment, temperatures, and reaction times, in this book or similar literature.)

In most methods, titanium(IV) chloride is heated while a stream of hydrogen is passed through:

$$\ce{2 TiCl4 + H2 -> 2 TiCl3 + 2 HCl}$$

If pure titanium metal is available, titanium(III) chloride can be prepared by separate placing of titanium(IV) chloride and titanium in stoichiometric proportions in a thick-wall quartz tube and heating of the tube using a temperature gradient. (Note that an explosion shield is recommended for this method.)

$$\ce{3 TiCl4 + Ti -> 4 TiCl3}$$

A simple method is the reduction of titanium(IV) chloride with freshly prepared antimony by heating in a melt-sealed bomb tube.

$$\ce{3 TiCl4 + Sb -> 3 TiCl3 + SbCl3}$$